# Cannot access json with getJson function

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to switch over to using jQuery for everything. I can't quite figure out why this function won't work. I have a simple JSON file with the following:

```
 {  "status" : "active" }
```

I'm just checking to see if something has been switched to an on state or not. I made simple page just to check my json request but I'm getting undefined back from the alert.

```
<html>
<script scr="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var results;;
$(document).read(function (){
  $.getJSON('myurl.com/myFile.json'),
     function(result){
       alert(result);a
     }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'm not sure why is coming up undefined.  At worse I would think it would come up as `[Object][object]`?

Comment: loose the ')' after url.

Comment: Please paste in the actual code, what you have there will not exhibit the behaviour you described.

Comment: For starters, please read the error console. Just after you fix `SyntaxError:  `TypeError: read is not a function on line 5`, a JShint should reveal some more warnings to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     $.getJSON('myurl.com/myFile.json',function(result){
          alert(result);
     });
});
```

- It should be `$(document).ready` not `$(document).read`
- Remove the extra `a` after the alert.
- Remove the extra bracket after the url `'myurl.com/myFile.json')` <-- This one
- Please have a look at the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) before starting something new.

Comment: it's accidentally relative

Comment: none of those small typo errors are actually within my code.  I just typed that real fast as the code was on another network.  I just needed to put the ')' after the url in the right spot.  Always makes me laugh how many dudes come out of the woodwork all hateration-like.  But there's always a few truly hopefull people not trying to up their reputation.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $.getJSON('myurl.com/myFile.json',function(result){
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

for Correct syntax   see this - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/  and http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  $.getJSON('myurl.com/myFile.json'),
     function(result){
       alert(result.status);
     }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This definitely won't solve his problem. `.read()` isn't a function and there's an extra `)` after the url.

Comment: Actually it did.  Joe  and shakib were right that I needed to lose the  ')' and then you were right with the '.status'.  Thanks people...I knew it was something simple...usually is.